# How to measure execution time of methods on app startup

Tags: android, android-studio

How can we find the execution time of each methods on app startup using Android Studio's Profiler . I need to find the methods that are making the app slow to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) you have official documentation. It is well documentated. It depends a bit on version of Android Studio that you are using.

But in short:

Android Studio 3.4.1

[image]

[image]

You click CPU and "Record".

[image]

After you finish recording you can select what you want to see.
[image]

Hover on methods you want to see.

[image]